# How do I update a given value in my pyglet window?

Tags: python, pyglet

#Noobquestion.
I want valueA to get updated every n seconds in the window.
I have this at the moment:

```
#returns a number from a website
def webSrapper(): 
    [Code]
    returns (valueA)

window = pyglet.window.Window(1280, 720)

label = pyglet.text.Label('Itemcount: ' +webSrapper())

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
    
pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the `pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(function, dt)` function.  It takes a function and a period to call it, then runs that function periodically. In your case, you would do something like

```
from pyglet import clock

#your code

def update_label(dt):
    label.text = 'Itemcount: ' +webSrapper()
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update_label, 5)

pyglet.app.run
```

This would set the text of `label` to `'Itemcount: ' +webSrapper()` every 5 seconds.  The reason the function `update_label` needs the `dt` argument is because `pyglet.clock.schedule_interval` always passes the time since it was last run as `dt`.

I got all of this information from https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/time.html